# Função UPDATE do MySQL está editando direito, mas cria uma nova linha vazia no final da tabela

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estou quebrando a cabeça aqui, pois a função `UPDATE` funciona de boas quando usada pura pelo terminal ou pelo Workbench, mas quando eu faço pelo código PHP via parâmetros do formulário HTML, ela edita direitinho também, mas cria uma nova linha vazia, e vai criando mais e mais linhas vazias cada vez que se edita algo. E isso não acontece via terminal e Workbench. (Pensei que tinha algo haver com a data no TIMESTAMP, então eu exclui o campo data do BD e do PHP mas o problema continuou).

```
<h1> Editar </h1>
<form method="post" action="<?php require('editar.php'); echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) ?>" >

id: <br><input type="number" name="id_upd">
<br><br>

Nome: <br><input type="text" name="nome_upd">
<br><br>

Localização: <br><input type="text" name="localizacao_upd">

<br><br>

E-mail: <br><input type="text" name="email_upd">
<br><br>

Website: <br><input type="text" name="website_upd">
<br><br>

Gênero:
<input type="radio" name="genero_upd" value="Feminino">Feminino
<input type="radio" name="genero_upd" value="Masculino">Masculino

<br><br>

Mensagem:<br> 
<textarea name="mensagem_upd" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
<br>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "*******";
$dbname = "guestbook";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $edit = $id_upd = $nome_upd = $localizacao_upd = $email_upd = $website_upd = $genero_upd = $mensagem_upd = "";

//Inserindo os dados de entrada do usuário recebidos do formulário HTML nas váriaveis
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    $id_upd = $_POST["id_upd"];
    $nome_upd = $_POST["nome_upd"];
    $localizacao_upd = $_POST["localizacao_upd"];
    $email_upd = $_POST["email_upd"];
    $website_upd = $_POST["website_upd"];
    $genero_upd = $_POST["genero_upd"];
    $mensagem_upd = $_POST["mensagem_upd"];

}

//Se a entrada do usuário for diferente de "" (vazio) edite o nome para nova entrada.
if($nome_upd != "") {
        //Variável $sql recebe a notação de UPDATE MySQL com parâmetros (os valores serão a entrada do usuário)
        $sql = "UPDATE guestbook SET nome='".$nome_upd."' WHERE id='".$id_upd."'";

        //Preparação de confirmação individual
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

        //Execução da preparação individual
        $stmt->execute();
}

if($localizacao_upd != "") {
        $sql = "UPDATE guestbook SET localizacao='".$localizacao_upd."' WHERE id='".$id_upd."'";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
}

if($email_upd != "") {
        $sql = "UPDATE guestbook SET email='".$email_upd."' WHERE id='".$id_upd."'";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
}

if($website_upd != "") {
        $sql = "UPDATE guestbook SET website='".$website_upd."' WHERE id='".$id_upd."'";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
}

if($genero_upd != "") {
        $sql = "UPDATE guestbook SET genero='".$genero_upd."' WHERE id='".$id_upd."'";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
}

 if($mensagem_upd != "") {
        $sql = "UPDATE guestbook SET mensagem='".$mensagem_upd."' WHERE id='".$id_upd."'";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
 }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;
?>
```

[image: Antes de Editar]

[image: Depois de Editar]

Comment: Cada vez que vc chama `execute()` um update é feito.

Comment: Sim, mas tá protegido pelo if, e se esse fosse o caso era pra surgir várias linhas em branco e não apenas uma por edição.

Comment: Eu já mudei uma vez pra $stmt1, $stmt2 e etc e não adiantou, eu tbm tentei botar só uma execução depois de todos os if's e acabou que isso fez que apenas a última coluna escrita fosse editada.

Comment: A ideia é você editar todos os campos de uma só vez. Coloca o form dessa tela.

Comment: Mas, se eu editar todos os campos de uma vez, quando eu quiser editar apenas um campo (a localização por exemplo) os campos vazios apagam o resto do conteúdo.

Comment: Uma edição, em teoria, ja teria todos campos preenchidos antes.

Comment: Sim, se eu pegar o id 1 do fulano e só editar o nome e clicar em submit, o resto dos dados que eram pra ficar intactos, somem. Se eu fizer o código de editar todos de uma vez.

Comment: Edite a pergunta e coloque o form.

Comment: Normalmente se faz uma edição assim, ao clicar no link editar, é feita um busca por id no inicio da pagina, depois para cada campo, vc faz um `<input type="text" name="nome" value="<?php echo $registro['nome']; ?> " />`. Só não entendi o que é essa imagem ... isso é uma tela só? ou são vários e vc deixou em uma imagem so?

Comment: São duas telas, uma antes de editar e uma depois de editar. 

Não entendi isso que você falou.

Comment: Isso que você falou por último seria no caso de uma edição imprimir os valores em todos os campos? acho que assim da deve dá certo, pois com todos os valores  impressos nos campos a pessoa edita só o que ela quiser e envia novamente o que já estava escrito. Vou tentar fazer desse modo.

Comment: faltou alguns devido ao tamanho mas a ideia é essa: </br><?php
$set=''
if($localizacao_upd != "") {
 if $set !="" { $set = $set +", "}
 $set=", localizacao='".$localizacao_upd."'";
        
}

 if($mensagem_upd != "") {
    if $set !="" { $set = $set +", "}
    $set = $set +" mensagem='".$mensagem_upd."'";
}
if $set !="" {
 $sql = "UPDATE guestbook SET ".$set." WHERE id='".$id_upd."'";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
 $stmt->execute();
}

catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;

Comment: Não funciona, eu tentei mudar pro formato INSERT do PDO desse link http://www.mustbebuilt.co.uk/php/insert-update-and-delete-with-pdo/ , e desse http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18323065/update-query-with-pdo-and-mysql  mas ele não tá funcionando... 

Acho que vou deixar como está mesmo, criando essa nova linha em branco, tomara que não pese no banco de dados..

Comment: Pelo que entendi, o teu script faz update a cada condição satisfeita, o correto seria verificar, e só depois atualizar os campos quando todas as condiçoes forem satisfeitas.

Comment: Fiz o código completo, separei o HTML do PHP, coloquei print do programa em funcionamento e ainda votaram como se eu tivesse feito a pergunta mal feita. O problema foi que vocês não souberam responder e não me ajudaram em nada. 9 meses se passaram e tive que fazer tudo em Webmatrix ao invés do Mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Edição geralmente funciona dessa forma, ao clicar no link da página de listagem o usuário é redirecionado para o `editar.php`, nele é feito a pesquisa no banco de dados pelo id, que foi passado por `$_GET`.

Listagem.php

`$row` é listagem de todos os registros, tem um while/foreach antes desse link.

```
<a href="cadastros/editar.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']>EDITAR</a>"
```

Editar.php

Faça a pesquisa por id, com o valor recebido em `$_GET['id']`, depois feche a tag do php, crie o html do form, em cada campo adicione o atributo `value` e abra a tag do php e escreva o valor do respectivo campo com `$registro['nome_do_campo']`.

Recomendo criar um arquivo novo(`gravar.php`) para realizar o update e o insert.

Como você saber quando deve incluir ou atualizar o registro? Se existir um valor no campo `id_udp` ele é um update do contrario é um insert.

```
<?php
    include 'conexao.php';

    $id = !empty($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : 0;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM guestbook WHERE id = :id"
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':id', $id);
    $stmt->execute();

    $registro = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>

<form method="post" action="gravar.php">

id: <br><input type="hidden" name="id_upd" value="<?php echo $registro['id'];" />
<br><br>

Nome: <br>
      <input type="text" name="nome_upd" value="<?php echo $registro['nome_upd'];" />
<br><br>

Localização: <br><input type="text" name="localizacao_upd" value="<?php echo $registro['localizacao_upd'];" />  

demais campos ...

</form>
```

Comment: Eu tenho um arquivo pra cada um, um pra inserir, outro pra excluir e outro pra exibir. Todos estão em notação PDO e funcionam perfeitamente, o único que não funciona é o arquivo editar.php, ele só funciona com a notação sem PDO (que é o dessa pergunta), mas coloca uma linha em branco. 

Eu to tentando fazer no formato de notação com PDO, mas não tá funcionando, tanto que abri outra pergunta pra tentar solucionar aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/93755/update-com-pdo-via-formul%C3%A1rio-html?

Essa